# 'sessionManagement()','and()','csrf()','cors()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal

Tags: spring-boot

This is my AppConfig file. How can I resolve `'sessionManagement()','and()','csrf()','cors()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal`?

```java
package com.example.config;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests(Authorize->Authorize.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll())
        .addFilterBefore(new jwtValidator(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
             @Override
             public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                 CorsConfiguration cfg =  new CorsConfiguration();
                 cfg.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:4200"));
                 cfg.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                 cfg.setAllowCredentials(true);
                 cfg.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                 cfg.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
                 cfg.setMaxAge(3600L);
                 return cfg;
            }
        });
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods still exist but the way you invoke them has changed. You need to use the methods where you pass a `Customizer`, which in essence is a lambda as it is marked with `@FunctionalInterface`.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll())
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .sessionManagement(sessionManagementCustomizer -> sessionManagementCustomizer 
                            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                    **or**
                    .cors(corsCustomizer-> corsCustomizer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
    ...snip continued config
}

private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:4200"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
    configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);

    var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```